# Laravel Eloquent - Sort Collection by Column by Array's Order

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to be able to sort the results of my collection by the status column in specific order.

The idea is to paginate the collection but giving priority in a specific order: [2, 1, ...], so the pending listings are shown first and the other after!

Does anyone has an idea on such method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code of collection, how it looks like

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting Laravel Collection via Array of ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118361/sorting-laravel-collection-via-array-of-ids)

Comment: @miken32 thanks for the reply, kindly check the marked answer bellow, it is exactly what I wanted :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your status priority is not in numeric order (e.g. 2 > 1 > 3 > 0), you can alternatively pass a callback function to sortBy:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'A', 'status' => 0],
    ['name' => 'B', 'status' => 3],
    ['name' => 'C', 'status' => 0],
    ['name' => 'D', 'status' => 1],
    ['name' => 'E', 'status' => 2],
    ['name' => 'F', 'status' => 1],
    ['name' => 'G', 'status' => 3],
    ['name' => 'H', 'status' => 1],
    ['name' => 'I', 'status' => 2],
    ['name' => 'J', 'status' => 3],
]);

// define status priority here
$statusPriorities = [2, 1, 3, 0];

$collection->sortBy(function($order) use($statusPriorities){
   return array_search($order['status'], $statusPriorities);
})->values()->all();
```

Output:

```
[
     [
       "name" => "I",
       "status" => 2,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "E",
       "status" => 2,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "D",
       "status" => 1,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "F",
       "status" => 1,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "H",
       "status" => 1,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "B",
       "status" => 3,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "G",
       "status" => 3,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "J",
       "status" => 3,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "A",
       "status" => 0,
     ],
     [
       "name" => "C",
       "status" => 0,
     ],
   ]
```

Comment: how would I set about doing that but with eloquent (model) and with paginate?

Comment: Important: when not all possible values are listed in the prioritized order list, additionally use `in_array`, otherwise those not found values will be at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

> Referring to laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby you can sort collection by column like...

```
$tasks = App\Task::all();
$tasks1 = $tasks->sortBy('title');
return $tasks1->values()->all();
//values() method is used to preserve array original keys
//You can also user sortByDesc, to get reverse order of your collection.
```

**As you can see it has been sorted by title in asc order**

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Akhtar",
        "created_at": "2019-09-01 14:18:05",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-01 14:18:05"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Hamid khan",
        "created_at": "2019-09-01 14:18:05",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-01 19:19:18"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Zarif",
        "created_at": "2019-09-04 19:14:18",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-04 19:14:18"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "testing",
        "created_at": "2019-09-01 13:01:39",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-01 13:01:39"
    }
]
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, but this answer is not what I was looking for!

Comment: It's exactly the same thing as above answer. but its okay not a problem

Comment: It isn't, the idea was to use an array to set the order of priorities on that column... @CBrach answered it perfectly!

Comment: I was also going that way, and i was doing the samething i was editing my answer. but np dear